# Configure Function Level Serialization Options Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams Binder

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We are using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams Binder to implement our streaming topology.Due to an organization level policy, services at my company can not register schemas to Kafka topics at runtime. However there's an except for internal topics required when using the KStreams DSL.
We have not been succesful configuring the SpecificAvroSerde in order set `auto.register.schemas=false` on at the function level for outbound serialization.

I have tried setting the configuration several ways.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.functionbean.configuration.producerProperties.auto.register.schemas=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.functions.functionbean.configuration.auto.register.schemas=false
```

The serdes isn't declared in the binding because we are customizing the serde using programatic configuration

```
    @Bean(name = "customSerde")
    public Serde<Bean> customSerde() {

        final Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = initializeSecuredSerdeConfig();
        final Serde<Bean> specificRecordValueSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        specificRecordValueSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
        return specificRecordValueSerde;
    } 

    private Map<String, Object> initializeSerdeConfig() {

        final Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
        serdeConfig.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        serdeConfig.put(AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, false);
        serdeConfig.put(SECURITY_PROTOCOL, secProtocol);

        // Missing the below 2 properties will throw 401 on Schema Registry operations.
        serdeConfig.put(BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_SOURCE, basicAuthCredentialsSource);
        serdeConfig.put(BASIC_AUTH_USER_INFO, basicAuthUserInfo);
        
        
        return serdeConfig;
    }
```

but the custom configuration above seems to get overwritten by the framework which resovles the serde to use for the bean.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5wyF.png)

If I set

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.auto.register.schemas=false
```

then internal topics such as "change-log" topic will not have schemas registered.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration must be

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.binding-name.producer.configuration.auto.register.schemas=false
```

where binding name is "functionbean-out-0".